# visual studio find and replace has default file types

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Does anyone know how to remove the default "Look at these file types:" in Find and Replace?  In my VS, whenever the rare occasion I tell VS to look in just *.cs, or just *.less, when I open Find and Replace, it prepopulates it with the last one I used.  This only happens on my first Find and Replace after opening Visual Studio.  It's kind of annoying that it prepopulates on first start up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Find (or whichever version you require - 11.0 for me)

   2. Locate the items named Filter # (Filter, Filter 0, Filter 1, Filter 2, etc.)
   3. Look for the one whose value is the incorrect string of file types
   4. Modify the value of that item to be the empty string

Answer found here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/577602/look-at-these-file-types-field-remembers-the-value-forever

Comment: Is there a way to turn this setting off after I delete those values to not save that as a filter?

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't had the issue re-appear since making this change.

Comment: I think this is no longer where Visual Studio 2019 stores it. Any idea where it's at now?

Answer (score 9):

Rather than deleting the text in 'Look at these file types', select `*.*` from the drop down list. When you next open VS, it will default to `*.*`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Boo with that registry crap.