# Default options in Find and Replace search dialog in Visual Studio not updating

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Recently my Visual Studio (2013) just decided that the first time I did a Find in Files (Ctrl + shift + F), the "Match whole word" option would be checked.  Always.  I can turn it off and it will stay off until the next time I start VS (or start a new instance).  I have combed through the options, but could not find any settings related to this.

I disabled all my extensions and even tried resetting my environment (Tools -> Import and export settings -> Reset all settings) but still, every time I search, I have to remember to first uncheck the box.

[image]

Where is this setting stored and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found 2 things.

1. There is an extension called "[SmartFind](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/015611c4-b357-4672-8977-f3ec92f0b808)" that you can get in the extension gallery.  While fixing this particular error isn't exactly what it was meant to do, it works.  However, it felt like a Band-aid fix to me and I wanted to know where the setting actually lived...
2. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27954259/1467396) question and answer is about something different (related, but different), but got me to the right place.  The answer is to go to

   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<YOUR VERSION>\Find`

   - Note that `<YOUR VERSION>` can be found by going to Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio.  For 2013, the version is 12.

     [image: Version]

   Find the key `DialogOptions` and set the `WholeWord` portion to 0.

   [image: Registry]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the 'Look at these file types' dropdown.  It is blank - to have this screen update properly, put in the default search mask '*.*' - the page should now store settings properly.