# Remove entry from Find in Files > File Types dropdown

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I want to not never see these entries in the File Types dropdown. How can I get rid of them?

[image]

They seem to be no longer [stored in the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31535885/726127).

I would like them to be gone because I use the scroll wheel to switch between entries frequently and they can be a distraction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These values are still stored in the registry. But starting with VS 2017, you can have installed multiple instances of the same VS version, at least theoretically. So the settings for VS 2022 can no longer be stored in the main global registry, if you have multiple VS 2022 instances installed. Therefore, each VS instance has its own private registry.

So, you need to edit the corresponding private registry.

1. Find the correct VS folder. Each VS instance has its unique ID on your machine. This ID is a part of the settings path. The folder is `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<VS_MAJOR_VERSION>_<ID\`. For example, mine is `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_ddd925ca\`. If it ends with `Exp`, it's an experimental VS instance. Note, look in the `Local` path, not the `Roaming` which exists as well.
2. The private registry file is stored in this folder and is named `privateregistry.bin`. Create a backup of this file, just for sure. Close all running instances of VS.
3. Start `regedit` and load this file:
4. Click the `HKEY_USERS`. Click the `File` menu and choose `Load Hive`. Browse to the `privateregistry.bin` and select it.
5. Click the `Open` button. Type in a `Key Name`, which can be any name you want to assign to the hive while viewing it (for example, "VS 2022"), then click the `OK` button.
6. Now you can see and edit any settings. In your case, you will navigate to `Computer\HKEY_USERS\vs 2022\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<YOUR_VS_ID>\Find`. There are the keys that you want to delete: `GlobalFilters 0`, `GlobalFilters 1`, …

[image]

7. Unfortunately, you cannot leave any gaps in the numbering. After you delete some keys, you need to rename the following ones.

[image]

8. Select the "VS 2022" hive in the left tree, and from the `File` menu select `Unload hive`.

That's all. You can start VS and the entries in the Find dialog should be gone.

Comment: That is...amazing. Thank you! It worked. How on earth did you discover that!?

Comment: Well, I've been developing VS extensions for years, so I had to learn where all those VS settings have gone.